# groups: cannot find name for group ID 125

Tags: 12.04

I've recently uninstalled virtualbox and since then, everytime I open a terminal I get the following:

> groups: cannot find name for group ID 125

The output of /etc/group is here:

> http://pastebin.com/gysgpHra

I didn't want to paste the full output here, it's a bit long.

Strangely enough, there is no group 125 but as far as I remember that was assigned to the vboxusers group.

Google has not been helpful at all.

I see a similar question here:

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/131651/cannot-find-name-for-group-id-127

But I don't know what he's talking about here:

> But I've found it in the group- list
>
> Entry
>   vboxusers:x:127:peter

Can anyone point me the right direction?

Comment: Note: The pastebin link here is no longer existent and therefore this question is incomplete...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54953/error-message-id-cannot-find-name-for-group-id-after-logging-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sudo delgroup vboxusers` to completely remove that group, if the uninstallation of Virtualbox failed to do that. Then enter `id` in the terminal and your uid, gid, and the groups you belong to will be listed, and `vboxusers` shouldn't be there.

If this does not work you could simply reinstall Virtualbox with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall <virtualbox pkg names>` and then you might be able to remove the package cleanly with `sudo apt-get purge <virtualbox version>` (which would remove any configuration files) and then you could use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove any other files left by Virtualbox. Then you could try my first suggestion again.

Lastly, if these options are unsuccessful, but installing Virtualbox does show that group 125 is virtualbox, you could remove the Virtualbox users group (as detailed in my first suggestion with `sudo delgroup vboxusers`), **before** you uninstall Virtualbox. This may work as Virtualbox doesn't seem to be uninstalling correctly and seems to be leaving a partial group that can't easily be removed after uninstallation as it doesn't show up in /etc/group.

It also should be said that you need to **logout** and **login** again for any changes to users and groups to take effect.

Comment: I tried all solutions mentioned in this post but id 125 is still there: uid=1000(michael) gid=1000(michael) groups=1000(michael),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare),125 - when I reinstall virtualbox, 125 does show that it's vboxusers.

Comment: Well, this is what I usually do when I get an error about a missing group; I'll see if I can think of something else to try.

Comment: I've edited my post with another suggestion; it might be helpful.

Comment: Same thing. 125 still just sits in my id :(

Comment: Did you logout and login again?

Comment: Wow - now I feel like an idiot, rebooted and it was fixed. Thank you so much for the help though.

Comment: Great! I should mark it as solved now.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and the reason was that I added user to a group `docker` manually with

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker hassan
```

and later when I uninstalled docker.io, I removed the group with

```
sudo groupdel docker
```

so after that, I used to get the following:

```
$ groups
hassan adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare libvirtd
groups: cannot find name for group ID 999
```

So to fix this I simply logged out and logged back in and that was it. You can test simply by doing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and login in. Then give the `groups` command and you will not see the same error message again.

Comment: indeed, I suspected me removing docker was the issue, but wasn't sure how to check and resolve. It seems on my machine as well docker had `999` as id. Thanks for mentioning the solution, even though it seems simple.

Comment: Log in and out didn't help. Only reboot helped. Not sure why. Linux Mint

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was actually prety simple. In my case, someone had changed the priviledges of /etc/group, and had removed all rwx from me. So the system saw I did not have the priviledge to access the name of the group I nbelonged, so it printed this message.
Maybe something similar migh be happening in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after uninstalling Chrome Remote Desktop for Linux, except in my case it was gid 1003:

```
groups: cannot find name for group ID 1003
paul@Chameleon:~$ groups
paul adm cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev lpadmin pulse sambashare vboxusers groups: cannot find name for group ID 1003
1003
paul@Chameleon:~$
```

What resolved the issue for me was rewriting the user account's groups using the `usermod` command:

```
sudo usermod -G paul,adm,cdrom,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare,vboxusers,pulse  paul
```

After issuing that command, I verified it resolved the issue by switching to VT1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), logged in, and observed the error was no longer displayed.

Answer (score -2):

Check `/etc/nscd.conf` make sure that the following line is there:

```
 enable-cache            group           yes
```